# Convergence/Divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

I'm stuck in a problem "Using Limit Comparison Test determine for which values of **p** the series converges or diverges to" $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^p*\log_{10}k}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For $p\gt 1$, converges.  For $p\lt 1$, diverges.  Integral test both cases.  For $p=1$, try to work it out.

Comment: This is a multiple of a *Bertrand's series* If you can read French, you should take a look at the [dedicated Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand).